# Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'- Folium

Tags: python, pandas, folium

I have a dataframe that looks like below

```
    Number  Names   latitude    longitude
0   1       Josh    25.713277   80.746531
1   2       Jon     25.713277   80.746531
2   3       Adam    25.713277   80.746531
3   4       Barsa   25.713277   80.746531
4   5       Fekse   25.713277   80.746531
5   6       Bravo   25.713277   80.746531
6   7       Levine  25.713277   80.746531
7   8       Talyo   25.713277   80.746531
8   9       Syden   25.713277   80.746531
9   10      Zidane  25.713277   80.746531
```

I am trying to create a folium map for this dataframe, I wanted the `Number`
column **values** to be displayed in some color based on the values of `Names` column with the following code, basically I want the number **1 to 10** to be displayed in some color for a place based on the Names. For example, `1` should be displayed in `lightblue`, `2` should be displayed in `green` color and rest of the numbers should be displayed in `red` color

```
for Number,Names,latitude,longitude in zip(dsa['Number'],dsa['Names'],dsa['latitude'],dsa['longitude']):
    folium.Marker(location=[latitude,longitude],
                  icon=folium.DivIcon(
                      html=f"""<div style="font-family: courier new; color: {'lightblue' if Names == 'Josh' else 'green' if Names == 'Jon' else 'red'}">{"{:.0f}".format(Number)}</div>""")
                  ).add_to(m)
m.save(os.path.join('color_popups1231.html'))
```

But when I execute this I am getting this error:

```
ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What is your Python version? `f` strings were only introduced in Python3.6.

Comment: Python version is 3.6.4

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The `f` format code in `"{:.0f}".format(Number)` for the Python string formatter requires a floating number, and yet you're passing to it the variable `Number`, which is derived from `dsa['Number']`, a string value from the dataframe. You should convert `Number` to a floating number before passing it to the formatter with `"{:.0f}".format(float(Number))` instead.